# Run Settings for XUnit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, xunit

The [`dotnet test` documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test?tabs=netcore21) states that arguments can be passed as pairs to unit tests.

> RunSettings arguments
>
> Arguments passed as RunSettings configurations for the test. Arguments
>   are specified as `[name]=[value]` pairs after "-- " (note the space
>   after --). A space is used to separate multiple `[name]=[value]` pairs.

I am using Xunit - How do I read these key/value pairs in my test code?

Comment: Seems like, xUnit isn't support that https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/636 Only VSTest runner has such possibility You can try to use their json configuration https://xunit.github.io/docs/configuring-with-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by using the `Environment` class to directly read the command line parameters explicitly (note: incomplete at time of writing):

```
public class Parameters
{
    public static string GetCommandLineArg(params string[] args)
        => Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().SkipWhile(x => !args.Contains(x, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();

    public static string ResultsDirectory => GetCommandLineArg("-r", "--result-directory");
    public static string Logger => GetCommandLineArg("-l", "--logger");
}
```

Comment: I'm dealing with the same issue. Now that it's been a few months, is this what you ended up doing? any more code to share to speed it up for the next guy who runs into this? Would you do this again or switch to using Nunit?

Comment: Does this solution work when picking the .runsettings file in Test Explorer?

Comment: just searching for something like this, why not read a "runsettings.json" file, to get same behaviour?

Comment: @MattLengenfelder I'm not running it in the explorer, so I haven't tried that.

Comment: @TomerW I believe that's what I did in the end, but there was a problem doing that in the beginning. I forget exactly what now, but I think I was trying really hard to config from the command line to avoid having to write out the json file.